# Grunt/SASS: Output CSS into a single file, and keep source mapping true to multiple source files

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm setting up SASS source maps (grunt-contrib-sass) in a Grunt task. Ideally all my projects' CSS would be combined into one file, and keep source maps true to the original source.

My initial thought was that it would be easiest just to keep the output source in separate files, which would make it easy, since mapping would be 1-to-1, with one .css output file for each .scss source file. But that wouldn't be an ideal solution going forward for the rest of our projects, as we'd like to keep HTTP requests to a minimum.

I can see how I can combine my source files, and output SASS from that, for one output file, or I could concat my .css output after SASS exports it, but obviously, mapping would not be true in either of these implementations.

It seems like this would have to be a feature of grunt-contrib-sass, but I'm not finding such a feature.

My SASS config looks like this:

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './src/',
                src: ['**/*.scss', '**/*.sass'],
                dest: './dist',
                ext: '.css'
            }],
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
            }

        }
    },
```

I tried the style options in the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass), and found only two of the four, 'compressed' and 'expanded' actually work. 'compact' and 'nested' do not work. I don't see an option that looks specific to what I need.

How can I output from SASS into a single CSS file, and keep source mapping true to multiple source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For outputting all of your styles into a single CSS stylesheet, I would recommend having one `main.scss` file in the root of your scss directory where you put `@import` statements to include all of the other scss files you'd like in the correct order.

Make sure to prepend all of the partial filenames (the files you are importing) with an underscore `_` like `_homepage-styles.scss`. This is important as it tells the sass compiler to ignore compiling these files down to their CSS equivalents. Thus, the compiler will output a CSS file for each SCSS file *without* the underscore `_`.

So your output would be `main.css`

---

For sourcemaps, add this under the options on your SASS config:

```
options: {
    'sourcemap': 'auto'
}
```

It should map down to the individual scss files. :)

Comment: That's great! Now the only issue is that my `.css` files, are still outputted as separate files, even though I prefixed them with the underscore, and included through SASS imports. Is there a way to combine those into the output, or do I need to convert them to SASS?

Comment: Hmm, what version of grunt-contrib-sass are you using? This seems to have been an issue in the past, but was resolved. However, there is a workaround to add an ignore pattern in the `src: ['**/*.scss', '**/*.sass', '!**/_*.scss', '!**/_*.sass'],` which tells it to exclude the ones that begin with `_`

(issue on github: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/72)

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood... do you mean that have also `.css` _source_ files? Yes, you will have to convert them to sass if you want to use sass to import them into one main css file with the sass compile process... Sass should be a superset of css, so just changing the file-extension to `.scss` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to compile to separate files for dev, but concat css files for production. This might be the obvious solution, as we wouldn't want map files to be loaded in production anyways.

But it would still be easier if there was an option for combined files straight out of the box.